# Connect VB app to WordPress

Tags: vb.net, wordpress

I'm wanting to write an app with visual basic 2008 that can post to my wordpress blogs. Has anyone done something similar? I'm looking for some relevant links or advice to get started.

Answer (score 2):

Hi you need to use [XML-RPC](http://www.xmlrpc.com/).

See this links:

- [MetaWeblogAPI VisualBasic .NET Code Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905668.aspx)
- [XML-RPC.NET](http://www.xml-rpc.net/)
- [Using XML RPC With VB.NET](http://www.beansoftware.com/Windows-Forms-Tutorials/Using-XML-RPC-With-VB.NET.aspx)
- [Calling the WordPress XMLRPC API from VB.net](http://www.emadibrahim.com/2007/07/31/calling-the-wordpress-xmlrpc-api-from-vbnet/)

Bye.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress uses the AtomPub protocol to remotely administer blogs. It uses https requests and xml data. I know that .NET has a very rich and easy to use interface for the web, found in namespace System.Web, and great tools for the manipulation of XML data, found in namespace System.Xml.

EDIT:

oops forgot to add in the link to the AtomPub page at the wordpress codex:

http://codex.wordpress.org/AtomPub